# Google Nest Hub - Scrolling list response causes default fallback intent to trigger

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google, google-home

**On Google Nest Hub:**

If I attempt to scroll through a long list response while the Dialogflow Agent is still speaking, it triggers the default fallback. If I wait for the Agent to stop speaking, I'm able to scroll up/down on the list with no problems.

A similar bug is reported here for someone using the Jovo Google Action framework: https://github.com/jovotech/jovo-framework/issues/605[1](https://github.com/jovotech/jovo-framework/issues/605)

In attempt to recreate the error, I made a new Actions on Google Project using boilerplate code for the list response.

This error did in fact show up again. No problems when I test it on a phone/tablet. Seems to be unique to the Google Home Hub.

Here's where I got the boilerplate code: 
https://developers.google.com/assistant/conversational/responses#list[2](https://developers.google.com/assistant/conversational/responses#list)

Here's the code I used to recreate the error:

```
'use strict';

const {
  dialogflow,
  List,
  Image
} = require('actions-on-google');
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

const app = dialogflow({
  debug: true
});

app.intent('List1', (conv) => {
  if (!conv.screen) {
    conv.ask('Sorry, try this on a screen device or select the ' +
      'phone surface in the simulator.');
    return;
  }

  conv.ask('This is a long conversational response. If you try to scroll/browse the list response while I\'m talking right now, it\'s going to trigger the default fallback. You have to wait until I\'m done talking to successfully scroll the list.');
  // Create a list
  conv.ask(new List({
    title: 'List Title',
    items: {
      // Add the first item to the list
      '1': {
        synonyms: [],
        title: '1',
        description: 'Pixel. Phone by Google.',
        image: new Image({
          url: 'https://storage.googleapis.com/actionsresources/logo_assistant_2x_64dp.png',
          alt: 'Image alternate text',
        }),
      },
      // Add the second item to the list
      '2': {
        synonyms: [],
        title: '2',
        description: 'Pixel. Phone by Google.',
        image: new Image({
          url: 'https://storage.googleapis.com/actionsresources/logo_assistant_2x_64dp.png',
          alt: 'Google Home',
        }),
      },
      // Add the third item to the list
      '3': {
        synonyms: [],
        title: '3',
        description: 'Pixel. Phone by Google.',
        image: new Image({
          url: 'https://storage.googleapis.com/actionsresources/logo_assistant_2x_64dp.png',
          alt: 'Google Pixel',
        }),
      },
      '4': {
        synonyms: [],
        title: '4',
        description: 'Pixel. Phone by Google.',
        image: new Image({
          url: 'https://storage.googleapis.com/actionsresources/logo_assistant_2x_64dp.png',
          alt: 'Google Pixel',
        }),
      },
      '5': {
        synonyms: [],
        title: '5',
        description: 'Pixel. Phone by Google.',
        image: new Image({
          url: 'https://storage.googleapis.com/actionsresources/logo_assistant_2x_64dp.png',
          alt: 'Google Pixel',
        }),
      },
      '6': {
        synonyms: [],
        title: '6',
        description: 'Pixel. Phone by Google.',
        image: new Image({
          url: 'https://storage.googleapis.com/actionsresources/logo_assistant_2x_64dp.png',
          alt: 'Google Pixel',
        }),
      },
      '7': {
        synonyms: [],
        title: '7',
        description: 'Pixel. Phone by Google.',
        image: new Image({
          url: 'https://storage.googleapis.com/actionsresources/logo_assistant_2x_64dp.png',
          alt: 'Google Pixel',
        }),
      },
      '8': {
        synonyms: [],
        title: '8',
        description: 'Pixel. Phone by Google.',
        image: new Image({
          url: 'https://storage.googleapis.com/actionsresources/logo_assistant_2x_64dp.png',
          alt: 'Google Pixel',
        }),
      },
      '9': {
        synonyms: [],
        title: '9',
        description: 'Pixel. Phone by Google.',
        image: new Image({
          url: 'https://storage.googleapis.com/actionsresources/logo_assistant_2x_64dp.png',
          alt: 'Google Pixel',
        }),
      },
      '10': {
        synonyms: [],
        title: '10',
        description: 'Pixel. Phone by Google.',
        image: new Image({
          url: 'https://storage.googleapis.com/actionsresources/logo_assistant_2x_64dp.png',
          alt: 'Google Pixel',
        }),
      },
      '11': {
        synonyms: [],
        title: '11',
        description: 'Pixel. Phone by Google.',
        image: new Image({
          url: 'https://storage.googleapis.com/actionsresources/logo_assistant_2x_64dp.png',
          alt: 'Google Pixel',
        }),
      },
      '12': {
        synonyms: [],
        title: '12',
        description: 'Pixel. Phone by Google.',
        image: new Image({
          url: 'https://storage.googleapis.com/actionsresources/logo_assistant_2x_64dp.png',
          alt: 'Google Pixel',
        }),
      },
      '13': {
        synonyms: [],
        title: 'Google Pixel',
        description: 'Pixel. Phone by Google.',
        image: new Image({
          url: 'https://storage.googleapis.com/actionsresources/logo_assistant_2x_64dp.png',
          alt: 'Google Pixel',
        }),
      },
      '14': {
        synonyms: [],
        title: '14',
        description: 'Pixel. Phone by Google.',
        image: new Image({
          url: 'https://storage.googleapis.com/actionsresources/logo_assistant_2x_64dp.png',
          alt: 'Google Pixel',
        }),
      },
      '15': {
        synonyms: [],
        title: '15',
        description: 'Pixel. Phone by Google.',
        image: new Image({
          url: 'https://storage.googleapis.com/actionsresources/logo_assistant_2x_64dp.png',
          alt: 'Google Pixel',
        }),
      },
      '16': {
        synonyms: [],
        title: '16',
        description: 'Pixel. Phone by Google.',
        image: new Image({
          url: 'https://storage.googleapis.com/actionsresources/logo_assistant_2x_64dp.png',
          alt: 'Google Pixel',
        }),
      },
      '17': {
        synonyms: [],
        title: '17',
        description: 'Pixel. Phone by Google.',
        image: new Image({
          url: 'https://storage.googleapis.com/actionsresources/logo_assistant_2x_64dp.png',
          alt: 'Google Pixel',
        }),
      },
      '18': {
        synonyms: [],
        title: '18',
        description: 'Pixel. Phone by Google.',
        image: new Image({
          url: 'https://storage.googleapis.com/actionsresources/logo_assistant_2x_64dp.png',
          alt: 'Google Pixel',
        }),
      },
      '19': {
        synonyms: [],
        title: '19',
        description: 'Pixel. Phone by Google.',
        image: new Image({
          url: 'https://storage.googleapis.com/actionsresources/logo_assistant_2x_64dp.png',
          alt: 'Google Pixel',
        }),
      },
      '20': {
        synonyms: [],
        title: '20',
        description: 'Pixel. Phone by Google.',
        image: new Image({
          url: 'https://storage.googleapis.com/actionsresources/logo_assistant_2x_64dp.png',
          alt: 'Google Pixel',
        }),
      },
      '21': {
        synonyms: [],
        title: '21',
        description: 'Pixel. Phone by Google.',
        image: new Image({
          url: 'https://storage.googleapis.com/actionsresources/logo_assistant_2x_64dp.png',
          alt: 'Google Pixel',
        }),
      },
      '22': {
        synonyms: [],
        title: '22',
        description: 'Pixel. Phone by Google.',
        image: new Image({
          url: 'https://storage.googleapis.com/actionsresources/logo_assistant_2x_64dp.png',
          alt: 'Google Pixel',
        }),
      },
      '23': {
        synonyms: [],
        title: '23',
        description: 'Pixel. Phone by Google.',
        image: new Image({
          url: 'https://storage.googleapis.com/actionsresources/logo_assistant_2x_64dp.png',
          alt: 'Google Pixel',
        }),
      },
      '24': {
        synonyms: [],
        title: '24',
        description: 'Pixel. Phone by Google.',
        image: new Image({
          url: 'https://storage.googleapis.com/actionsresources/logo_assistant_2x_64dp.png',
          alt: 'Google Pixel',
        }),
      },
      '25': {
        synonyms: [],
        title: '25',
        description: 'Pixel. Phone by Google.',
        image: new Image({
          url: 'https://storage.googleapis.com/actionsresources/logo_assistant_2x_64dp.png',
          alt: 'Google Pixel',
        }),
      },
    },
  }));
});

app.intent('List - OPTION', (conv, params, option) => {
  const SELECTED_ITEM_RESPONSES = {
    '1': '1',
    '2': '2',
    '3': '3',
    '4': '4',
    '5': '5',
    '6': '6',
    '7': '7',
    '8': '8',
    '9': '9',
    '10': '10',
    '11': '11',
    '12': '12',
    '13': '13',
    '14': '14',
    '15': '15',
    '16': '16',
    '17': '17',
    '18': '18',
    '19': '19',
    '20': '20',
    '21': '21',
    '22': '22',
    '23': '23',
    '24': '24',
    '25': '25',
  };
  conv.ask(SELECTED_ITEM_RESPONSES[option]);
  conv.ask('Which response would you like to see next?');
});

exports.dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be related to the Google Nest Hub firmware version.

I was able to resolve this issue by joining Google's "[Preview Program](https://support.google.com/googlenest/answer/6343937?hl=en)", which updated my Nest Hub firmware.

Previous firmware version: 1.42.171872
Current firmware : 1.44.191160